# onKeyPress eventhandler on component is not invoked

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with a key event no firing

```
...
keybinding: function(event) {
    console.log('keysdads', event);
  },


return (
  <ul id='list-view' style={this.props.style} onKeyPress={this.keybinding}>
    {listItems}
    {loading}
  </ul>
);
```

The `keybinding` function doesn't get called. However, if i instead pass in `onKeyPress={this.keybinding()}` it fires, but doesnt pass in the event

any ideas?

Comment: onkeypress is **usually** used for inputs because you can type and hence there is a onkeypress event. Why would you want a onkeypress event on `ul` element ? can you please explain your scenario more?

Comment: When the ul component is mounted, i want the onKeyPress event to be activated

Comment: but keypress doesn't work that way. If you have an text input element, onkeypress works. Because you cannot type ON a `ul` element